# How to fix this typescript reference error

Tags: typescript

I am seeing typescript error with following code even though i mentioned as Record<"abc", string> ?

```
interface IFoo {
  key ?:
    | string
    | Record<"abc", string>
    | boolean
    | string[]
}
const test: IFoo = {key: {abc: "Hi"}}
console.log(test?.key?.abc);

Property 'abc' does not exist on type 'string | Record<"abc", string>'.
  Property 'abc' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8CwAUMsgNYQCeyA-AFxEkkA+yAzmFKAOYOMsBKEBJigATADwAiOACMEkgDRsO3AHxEAvkWEh2ySO1posOALx5yFI7lkIjkgBLBJGrYR2tMAGwgA6L5hcABQGYNS+luG2AJQA3ERAA

Comment: This is how unions work. As not all cases have an `abc` property you have to discriminate between them before you can access it. There are several ways, one of which is `if ("abc" in test.key) console.log(test.key.abc)`

Comment: Sorry I meant `if (typeof test.key === "object" && "abc" in test.key) console.log(test.key.abc)`

Answer (score 0):

Since `test?.key` can be something else other than Record<"abc", string>, you can't access the property `abc`.

You could use a type coercion or type guards instead:

```
const key = test?.key;

if (isAbcRecord(key)) console.log(key.abc);

function isAbcRecord(v: unknown): v is Record<"abc", string> {
    return v && typeof v === "object" && !Array.isArray(v); // should suffice
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would go for restricted generics:

```
interface IFoo <T extends  string
    | Record<"abc", string>
    | boolean
    | string[]>{
  key ?:T
}
const test: IFoo<Record<"abc",string>> = {key: {abc: "Hi"}}
console.log(test?.key?.abc);
```

Comment: You've completely changed the meaning of the type.

Comment: yes. it can have other types as well

Comment: Sorry, I missed the union operator. Updated